# Ros with Labview: can see topics but no data

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
I've got a ROS node running on Labview on my PC (Windows 10, 192.168.1.129). It is publishing some data on a topic. ROS is installed on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu SO (18.04, IP: 192.168.1.130). I don't have ROS installed on Windows, so obviously the master is running on Raspberry PI 3. So my PC and Raspberry Pi are connected to the same network, and can communicate through ssh. If I ping each other, it works. But then, when I run the Publisher on Labview (on Windows), I mean when I run the node that publishes on a topic, from Ubuntu terminal I can see the topic, with “rostopic list”, but then with “rostopic echo” I can’t see anything. So then I try to ping the node publishing on Labview with “rosnode ping”, but it says: “ERROR: Communication with node[http://169.254.201.168:50436] failed!”. I’ve already done everything they say in other similar questions, I’ve edited the etc/host file on my PC adding the Ubuntu hostname and IP, and I’ve done the same on Ubuntu, adding my PC hostname and IP. I’ve turned off firewalls on Windows. I’ve exported ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP. Nothing works. Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352196/ros-with-labview:-can-see-topics-but-no-data/) by [Lol](https://answers.ros.org/users/54867/lol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solved it, if someone has the same problem, using "ROS for LabVIEW Software" from GitHub, entering "/user.lib/ROS for LabVIEW Software/ROS/Code/ROS_Tools/ROSTerminal.vi", you only have to change the node IP inside it!

---

Originally posted by [Lol](https://answers.ros.org/users/54867/lol/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [junwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/104185/junwen/) on 2022-05-05**:
Hello,I have a same question now.But I don't understand the way you solve. Can you explain in more detail?

**Comment by [beluga](https://answers.ros.org/users/39391/beluga/) on 2022-10-26**:
The source distribution should be set under build specs in the project in Lv. There is a pdf file under the "Help" folder of "ROS for LabView Software" folder (from github). Check "myRIO and roboRIO Help" named file.

**Comment by [Lol](https://answers.ros.org/users/54867/lol/) on 2022-12-07**:
Go to this [path](https://github.com/tuftsBaxter/ROS-for-LabVIEW-Software/blob/master/ROS%20for%20LabVIEW%20Software/ROS/Code/ROS_Tools/ROSTerminal.vi) or look for the *ROSTerminal.vi* file, and set MANUALLY your IP directly there.